# нажатие на onclick через webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне нажать на onclick через WebDriver? заранее спасибо.

```
<span class="surf_ckick" onclick="start_test('tests_view?id=067eb917f6aabc129964f767d155f47e', '2801'); this.style.textDecoration='line-through'; this.style.color='#FF3800'; ">Исто.рический </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, делаете клик по элементу:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("surf_ckick")).click();
```

При клике произойдет событие onclick и вызов соответствующей вашей функции `start_test`

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. При нажатии на эту кнопку должна открыться страница, но она не открывается, что делать ?

Comment: @as1andrey1 проверить консоль браузера на наличие ошибок JS и убедиться в работе функции start_test

Comment: Как бы кнопка нажалась, а страница не открывается

Comment: @as1andrey1 советую прочитать https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Comment: а может страница открывается во втрой вкладке ?

Comment: Ошибку нашёл, страница открывается во втором окне